# set color code in data image svg is not working

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to change color in data image svg, right now current color is `blue`, i want to change its color to this color code `#266C5E`, can anyone please help me how to do that ?

```
data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg id='squiggle-link' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:ev='http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events' viewBox='0 0 10 18'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E.squiggle%7Banimation:shift 1s linear infinite;%7D@keyframes shift %7Bfrom %7Btransform:translateX(-10px);%7Dto %7Btransform:translateX(0);%7D%7D%3C/style%3E%3Cpath fill='none' stroke='blue' stroke-width='1' class='squiggle' d='M0,17.5 c 2.5,0,2.5,-1.5,5,-1.5 s 2.5,1.5,5,1.5 c 2.5,0,2.5,-1.5,5,-1.5 s 2.5,1.5,5,1.5' /%3E%3C/svg%3E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to URL encode `#` in your svg code. So replace `blue` with `%23266C5E` instead of `#266C5E`(which `%23` is `#` URL encoded).

Here's the replaced version:

```
data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg id='squiggle-link' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:ev='http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events' viewBox='0 0 10 18'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E.squiggle%7Banimation:shift 1s linear infinite;%7D@keyframes shift %7Bfrom %7Btransform:translateX(-10px);%7Dto %7Btransform:translateX(0);%7D%7D%3C/style%3E%3Cpath fill='none' stroke='%23266C5E' stroke-width='1' class='squiggle' d='M0,17.5 c 2.5,0,2.5,-1.5,5,-1.5 s 2.5,1.5,5,1.5 c 2.5,0,2.5,-1.5,5,-1.5 s 2.5,1.5,5,1.5' /%3E%3C/svg%3E
```

```css
div {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg id='squiggle-link' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:ev='http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events' viewBox='0 0 10 18'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E.squiggle%7Banimation:shift 1s linear infinite;%7D@keyframes shift %7Bfrom %7Btransform:translateX(-10px);%7Dto %7Btransform:translateX(0);%7D%7D%3C/style%3E%3Cpath fill='none' stroke='%23266C5E' stroke-width='1' class='squiggle' d='M0,17.5 c 2.5,0,2.5,-1.5,5,-1.5 s 2.5,1.5,5,1.5 c 2.5,0,2.5,-1.5,5,-1.5 s 2.5,1.5,5,1.5' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```